# Can't wrap my head around Letter Pyramid problem

Tags: c++, c++11

```
// Letter Pyramid
// Written by Frank J. Mitropoulos

#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string letters{};

    std::cout << "Enter a string of letters so I can create a Letter Pyramid from it: ";
    getline(std::cin, letters);

    size_t num_letters = letters.length();

    int position {0};

    // for each letter in the string
    for (char c: letters) {

        size_t num_spaces = num_letters - position;
        while (num_spaces > 0) {
            std::cout << " ";
            --num_spaces;
        }

        // Display in order up to the current character
        for (size_t j=0; j < position; j++) {
            std::cout << letters.at(j);
        }

        // Display the current 'center' character
        std::cout << c;

        // Display the remaining characters in reverse order
        for (int j=position-1; j >=0; --j) {
            // You can use this line to get rid of the size_t vs int warning if you want
            auto k = static_cast<size_t>(j);
            std::cout << letters.at(k);
        }

        std::cout << std::endl; // Don't forget the end line
        ++position;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hello I am learning C++ as a beginner and I cannot seem to grasp the logic of this program. So For Example if I entered ABC the output would be:

```
    A
   ABA
  ABCBA
```

how does num_spaces give me the spaces? Also the Display in order up to the current character. He created a for loop but if I am reading this correctly wouldn't j be 0 and position be 0 so how would 0 < 0? and what does letters.at(j) have to do with it. I am very confused with most of the program if someone can explain it to me that would be great!

Comment: Use a debugger to run this program, one line at a time, to see how it works. This is what a debugger is for.

Comment: "I am very confused with most of the program" then maybe start with something simpler. Seriously, explaining every detail in this code from scratch can fill a week

Comment: i mean you dont need to understand how a combustion engine works to drive a car, but for example to fully grasp what a range based for loop does you need to understand container and iterators to some extend

Comment: I understand how a range loop works and all that but the problem is how does position give me spaces and how would j < position work because j is 0 and position is 0? and are these loops inside the for (char c: letters) loop I am assuming?

Comment: in the first iteration only one character is printed, the center one, called `c` in the code. What Sam said, you should use a debugger to see in detail what is going on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain to you, how the program works.

First the variable "letters" is defined as `std::string`. It is initialized with the empty braced default initialize and is hence empty.

All varaible should be initialized at the time of definition.

Then we ask the user of the program, to input a test string, by using the inserter operator to write the text to the console (std::cout).

Next, we read a complete line from the user. So, everything he types until he presses enter.

With `size_t num_letters = letters.length();` we get the number of characters that the user entered. Including spaces, bit with out the termination "\n" (produced by enter).

The length of the string is important for building the pyramid. The variable position is defined and initialized with 0. It is the indicater for the row that the program is working on. It will be incremented by 1 at the end of each loop run (of the range based for loop).

So, it starts with 0, then, in the next loop it will be one, then 2 and so on. Since the loop runs a much as we have letters in the given string, "position" will be equeal to the length of the string.

OK, nect the for loop runs. For each charachter in the string, we will have one loop run.

And now, the most important for you is the next line.

```
size_t num_spaces = num_letters - position;
```

For the string "ABC" `num_letters` is always 3. `position` is for the first loop 0, then 1 and then 2.

So, `num_spaces` will be first: 3, then 2 and then 1.

The while loop will print `num_spaces` spaces in that row. In the first row, it will print 3 spaces, in the next row 2 and then 1 space.

And after that it will write the correct letter.

With that mechanisme, we will get a pyamid effect.

The next loop will print letters from the original string. In the first loop: Nothing, because j is 0 and position is 0. In next loop it will print then A and then the B.

The next statement will print the current character. So, first A then B then C.

And then the rest will be printed in reverse order.

At the end we get a new line and then the variable position is incremented, to start a new row.

I hope this helps-

Comment: Thank you so much you explained in great detail I appreciate it!